# Can I load html pages from APK Expansion file into webview without unzipping?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, apk-expansion-files

I have a website in an APK expansion OBB file. I want to load this website in a webview in my app. Can I somehow load the website from the OBB file directly or do I have to unzip it first?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities exist.

First, you can provide access to these files via `content:` URIs. For that, you may consider using APEZProvider from Google Market Apk Expansion. Look at this page for an example: http://nullpointerexc.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/android-read-media-file-from-obb-using.html. The example deals with an mp4 file, but you can also do the same for html resources. The only caveat is that these files need to be stored non-compressed in the expansion apk, otherwise it will not work.

If you would prefer to store your website compressed, you can overload `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest` to decompress them on the fly (for example via `ZipResourceFile.getInputStream` from the same Google Market Apk Expansion).